# how to iterate through multiple elements in xml using R program

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

i am just new to R program and i am in the process of learning it.
I have a sample xml file as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>    
<documents>
<Attribute ID="HCITM0014870" MultiValued="false" ProductMode="Normal" FullTextIndexed="true" 
ExternallyMaintained="false" Derived="false" Mandatory="false">
  <Validation BaseType="text" MinValue="" MaxValue="" MaxLength="" InputMask=""/>
  <DimensionLink DimensionID="Language"/>
  <MetaData>
    <Value AttributeID="Attribute-Group-Order">1</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="DisplaySequence">1</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="Attribute-Order">8</Value>
  </MetaData>
  <AttributeGroupLink AttributeGroupID="HCCHP0002088"/>
  <UserTypeLink UserTypeID="CNS"/>
  <UserTypeLink UserTypeID="PRD"/>
</Attribute>

<Attribute ID="GroupSEO" MultiValued="false" ProductMode="Property" FullTextIndexed="false" 
 ExternallyMaintained="false" Derived="false" Mandatory="false">
<Name>Group SEO Name</Name>
<Validation BaseType="text" MinValue="" MaxValue="" MaxLength="1024" InputMask=""/>
<DimensionLink DimensionID="Language"/>
<MetaData>
<Value AttributeID="Attribute-Group-Order">1</Value>
<Value AttributeID="Enterprise-Label">NAV-GR-SEONAME</Value>
<Value ID="#NAMED" AttributeID="Attribute-Group-Name">#NAMED</Value>
<Value AttributeID="Enterprise-Description">Navigation Group SEO Name</Value>
<Value AttributeID="Attribute-Order">3</Value>
</MetaData>
<AttributeGroupLink AttributeGroupID="HTCategorizationsNavigation"/>
<AttributeGroupLink AttributeGroupID="HTDigitalServicesModifyClassifications"/>
<UserTypeLink UserTypeID="ENT-Group"/>
<UserTypeLink UserTypeID="NAVGRP"/>
<UserTypeLink UserTypeID="ENT-SubCategory"/>
<UserTypeLink UserTypeID="ENT-Category"/>
</Attribute>
</documents>
```

i want convert this xml into a data frame in R,this is my following code that i wrote to convert into data frame.

```
library(XML)
data=htmlParse("E:/Project/Sample.xml")
print(data)
fulltextindexed=xpathSApply(data,"normalize-space(//attribute/@fulltextindexed)")
ID=xpathSApply(data,"normalize-space(//attribute/@id)")
multivalued=xpathSApply(data,"normalize-space(//attribute/@multivalued)")
productmode=xpathSApply(data,"normalize-space(//attribute/@productmode)")
externallymaintained=xpathSApply(data,"normalize-space(//attribute/@externallymaintained)")
derived=xpathSApply(data,"normalize-space(//attribute/@derived)")
mandatory=xpathSApply(data,"normalize-space(//attribute/@mandatory)")
attribute.group.order=xpathSApply(data,"//value[@attributeid='Attribute-Group-Order']",xmlValue)
enterprise.description=xpathSApply(data,"//value[@attributeid='Enterprise-Description']",xmlValue)
user.type.id=paste(xpathSApply(data,"//usertypelink/@usertypeid"),collapse = "|")
df=data.frame(ID,fulltextindexed,multivalued,productmode,externallymaintained,derived,mandatory,attribute.group.order,enterprise.description,user.type.id)
print(df)
```

this is the output of my code

```
          ID fulltextindexed multivalued productmode externallymaintained derived mandatory attribute.group.order    enterprise.description                                          user.type.id
          1 HCITM0014870            true       false      Normal                false   false     false                     1 Navigation Group SEO Name CNS|PRD|ENT-Group|NAVGRP|ENT-SubCategory|ENT-Category
          2 HCITM0014870            true       false      Normal                false   false     false                     1 Navigation Group SEO Name CNS|PRD|ENT-Group|NAVGRP|ENT-SubCategory|ENT-Category
```

but as you can see even though my xml has two elements,the output is coming twice but only the first element is coming twice.I want the second element also.I have searched everywhere but could not find a solution for this.If anyone could help me it would be of great help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a few problems here, but I think the main one is that you need to have exactly 2 answers for every xpath query otherwise the length-1 queries will recycle in the resultant data frame. The safest way to do this is to make sure you have one single entry for each `Attribute` node and build the data frame row by row. You can do this with the aid of a simple helper function:

```r
Process <- function(vals)
{
  if(length(vals) == 0) return(NA)
  if(length(vals) == 1) return(vals)
  else return(paste(vals, collapse = " | "))
}
```

Now you can ensure that you generate only one element per cell, you can generate one row of your data frame for each "Attribute" node and stick them together with `rbind`.

Note I'll use the xml2 package instead of XML, though they are fairly similar.

**I am using the variable `xml` as the xml string from your question:**

```r
library(xml2)

df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(xml_find_all(read_xml(xml), "//Attribute"),
function(Attributes)
{
  ID <- Process(xml_attr(Attributes, "ID"))
  fulltextindexed <- Process(xml_attr(Attributes, "FullTextIndexed"))
  multivalued <- Process(xml_attr(Attributes, "MultiValued"))
  productmode <- Process(xml_attr(Attributes, "ProductMode"))
  externallymaintained <- Process(xml_attr(Attributes, "ExternallyMaintained"))
  derived <- Process(xml_attr(Attributes, "Derived"))
  mandatory <- Process(xml_attr(Attributes, "Mandatory"))
  attribute.group.order <- Process(xml_text(xml_find_all(Attributes, ".//Value[@AttributeID='Attribute-Group-Order']")))
  enterprise.description <- Process(xml_text(xml_find_all(Attributes, ".//Value[@AttributeID='Enterprise-Description']")))
  user.type.id <- Process(xml_attr(xml_find_all(Attributes, ".//UserTypeLink"), "UserTypeID"))

  return(data.frame(ID, fulltextindexed, multivalued, productmode,
                    externallymaintained, derived, mandatory,
                    attribute.group.order, enterprise.description, user.type.id,
                    stringsAsFactors = F))
}))
```

Now we can do

```
print(df)
            ID fulltextindexed multivalued productmode externallymaintained derived mandatory
1 HCITM0014870            true       false      Normal                false   false     false
2     GroupSEO           false       false    Property                false   false     false
```

Comment: Thanks man...that worked a lot, but why can't I use the package XML instead of xml2